# How do I Become a Theoretical Chemist/Physicist with a Chemistry Background?

Tags: united-kingdom, health

I have a Masters in Chemistry. I'm UK based, and in my early 30's. I live with family. I have Asperger's and psychosis.

I find chemical theories fun and interesting. I've dabbled in a little math and some physics. I enjoy the theory. It's like a story with missing pieces.

Would anyone be willing to share their experience of pursuing theoretical chemistry/physics as a career?

I'm interested in advice as well based upon my situation. How did you fare financially? How is your day to day life? Any regrets? Any issues you can see with my plan?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are looking for a career in academia, you probably need a doctorate. If in industry, this is off topic here. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry! I meant as a job, not as a lecturer.

Comment: There is a chem site here also, but it seems to be for academics as well. We won't be much help, I'm afraid. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

This post only responds to your final question.  Some things I'd ask yourself prior to pursuing your idea further:

1. How many people graduate with PhDs in Theoretical Chemistry?
2. What percentage end up doing research in an academic setting?
3. What opportunities are you personally willing to give up to pursue this path?
4. What are your chances of succeeding?

No one on this forum will be able to answer these second two questions for you, and honestly these are the most important questions.  Proprietary resources such as Lightcast will be able to help you with the first two questions, with at least some level of accuracy.  Lastly, here's hoping there are some Theoretical Chemists in this forum who answer your other questions.